# Empty String Textbox.Text inside lambda expression event listener

Tags: c#, winforms

feel like I'm missing something simple here.
Have a form that looks like this:

```
public partial class UpdateCustomerForm : Form
    {
        public UpdateCustomerForm(UpdateCustomer customer)
        {
            InitializeComponent();      

            updateCustomerBttn.Click += (sender, e) => HandleID(customer);

        }

        private void updateCustomerBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string customerName = nameTb.Text; // This works
            this.Close();

        }

        private void HandleID(UpdateCustomer customer)
        {
            //all below values are empty

            UpdateCustomer customerToUpdate = new UpdateCustomer()
            {
                CustomerID = customer.CustomerID,
                CustomerName = nameTb.Text,
                Address1 = addressTb.Text,
                Address2 = address2Tb.Text,
                Phone = phoneTb.Text,
                City = cityTB.Text,
                Country = countryTb.Text

            };

            Customer.UpdateCustomer(customerToUpdate);

            CustomerForm CustomerForm = (CustomerForm)Application.OpenForms["CustomerForm"];
            CustomerForm.PopulateDGV();

            
        }

    }
```

I don't understand why the .text values of all the textboxes are not represented in the HandleID method. All come in as empty strings. Is there something I need to do to be able to access the values?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the form that you are seeing is a different instance that the form which is running the code. Check the code that instantiate and shows the form.

Comment: In C#, the difference between `null` (in your question title) and "empty strings", in the last paragraph, is enormously important.

Comment: Try saving the _UpdateCustomer customer_ received in the constructor to a form level variable and pass that variable into the HandleId method

Comment: sorry - fixed title. @PepijnBakker - yes, all values except CustomerID are "", 
PopulateDGV(); just runs a SELECT to get the data from MySQL that is set in Customer.UpdateCustomer(customerToUpdate)

Comment: I noticed you close the window after pressing the button as well, but it is done in a separate method that is subscribed to the click event of your button. Could it be that your form is "closed" before `HandleID` gets executed? What happens if you move the `this.Close()` line to the end of the `HandleID`?

EDIT: this would also explain why the line in `updateCustomerBttn_Click` does work

Comment: @PepijnBakker yup! Looks like that was the problem. I was under the impression that the logic inside HandleID was executed before anything in the event handler was executed. 
updateCustomerBttn.Click += (sender, e) => HandleID(customer);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have an issue similar to this one:

There are two methods subscribed to the `Click` event here. The first one is:

```cs
updateCustomerBttn.Click += (sender, e) => HandleID(customer);
```

and the second one is:

```cs
private void updateCustomerBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

which is subscribed in `InitializeComponent()`.

Now, the problem here is that because `updateCustomerBttn` gets subscribed before `HandleID`, it also gets executed before `HandleID` when the event is called. Which means the Form is closed before `HandleID` gets executed, which is causing the problem.

You can of course change the order in which you subscribe the two methods, but you can already see that this can get really messy over time. So the better option is to move `this.Close()` to `HandleID`, or - if you wanna be really clean - add it to the lambda in the constructor:

```
public partial class UpdateCustomerForm : Form
{
    public UpdateCustomerForm(UpdateCustomer customer)
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
        updateCustomerBttn.Click += (sender, e) => {
            HandleID(customer);
            this.Close();
        };
    }

    private void HandleID(UpdateCustomer customer)
    {
        UpdateCustomer customerToUpdate = new UpdateCustomer()
        {
            CustomerID = customer.CustomerID,
            CustomerName = nameTb.Text,
            Address1 = addressTb.Text,
            Address2 = address2Tb.Text,
            Phone = phoneTb.Text,
            City = cityTB.Text,
            Country = countryTb.Text
        };

        Customer.UpdateCustomer(customerToUpdate);

        CustomerForm CustomerForm = (CustomerForm)Application.OpenForms["CustomerForm"];
        CustomerForm.PopulateDGV();
    }
}
```